# Labels and textbox sizing and aligning problems in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am working on a Bootstrap based form and struggling to get things to position properly.

I am trying to create a form consisting of labels/prompts and textboxes. The problems that I have with my code are

1. the label column (col-3) is too wide and reducing it to col-2 is too narrow. But I would like to make it narrower than what it is now.
2. the textboxes in the textbox column (col-4) are the same length but it does not matter what their class is, they don't get any wider. I would like them all wider.
3. not sure if I need col-5
4. I want the controls vertically middle within the row. They look like they are aligned to the top.

I have tried different classes and controls and cannot get something to work. This code will be put in a ASP.Net MVC project which is what the **@Html.TextBoxFor** is for, but I don't think this is an issue.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height:38px">
        <div class="col-3">Label 1:</div>
        <div class="col-4">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Textbox1)</div>
        <div class="col-5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height:38px">
        <div class="col-3">Label 2:</div>
        <div class="col-4">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Textbox2)</div>
        <div class="col-5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 actually has column management here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Specifically, col-sm-,col-md-,col-lg tags should assist you in choosing one thats the proper size